# Google robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I want to allow google robot:
1) to only see the main page
2) to see description in a search results for main page

I have the following code but it seems that it doesn't work

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /feed
Disallow: /site/terms-of-service
Disallow: /site/rules
Disallow: /site/privacy-policy
Allow: /$
```

Am I missing something or I just need to wait the google robot to visit my site?
Or maybe it is some action required from google webmaster panel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to disallow *all* pages except the home page, or do you want to disallow only specific pages (like `/feed`, `/site/rules` etc.) and allow everything else (including the home page)?

Comment: I want to allow only homepage.
I want to disallow another pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your robots.txt should work (and yes, it takes time), but you might want to make the following changes:

- It seems you want to target only Google’s bot, so you should use `User-agent: Googlebot` instead of `User-agent: *` (which targets all bots that don’t have a specific record in your robots.txt).
- It seems that you want to disallow crawling of *all* pages except the home page, so there is no need to specify a few specific path beginnings in `Disallow`.

So it could look like this:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
Allow: /$
```

Google’s bot may only crawl your home page, nothing else. All other bots may crawl everything.